# Implementing MTLModel shows error parsing json dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

The error messages go like this:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Channel 0x7fb34b5d1420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key user.'
```

And here's the code:

```
NSDictionary *json = @{@"u1" : @{@"handle" : @"h1", @"authToken" : @"123"}};
NSError *e = nil;
Channel *c = [[Channel alloc] initWithDictionary:json error:&e];
NSLog(@"channel.u1.handle: %@", c.u1.handle);
```

`Channel.m`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
        return @{
            @"u1" : @"u1"
        };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)u1Transformer {
    return [MTLJSONAdapter dictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[User class]];
}
```

`User.m`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
        return @{
            @"handle" : @"handle",
            @"authToken" : @"token"
        };
}
```

Using [Mantle, iOS json parsing framework](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle).

How do I parse my JSON into cocoa objects?

Answer (score 0):

One quick question: what version of `Mantle` are you using?

This line does not compile with `Mantle` `1.5.4`.

```
return [MTLJSONAdapter dictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[User class]];
```

To make this work, you'll need to change it to

```
return [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[User class]];
```

Also, if you want to use `initWithDictionary:error:` to initialise a `Channel` instance, you'll need to override that method, here's an example:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue 
                            error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionaryValue error:error];
    if(self){
        self.u1 = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:[dictionaryValue objectForKey:@"u1"] 
                                             error:error];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Or simply use `modelOfClass:fromJSONDictionary:error:` which is a static method of `MTLJSONAdapter`. In your case, you may have code like this:

```
NSDictionary *json = @{@"u1" : @{@"handle" : @"h1", @"authToken" : @"123"}};
NSError *e = nil;
Channel *c = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[Channel class] 
                       fromJSONDictionary:json 
                                    error:&e];
```

Hope this helps :)